# Regrouping raster values from range to one value using GRASS GIS?

Tags: raster, grass-gis

Using GRASS GIS is there a way to give a certain value for 3D raster cells that fall within a certain range, whether it's by using module (reclass, recode, r3.mapcalc)?

Another alternative would be to export the 3D raster as a point file and do this using MS Access, but I have not found a way to export a 3D raster as an xyz file (it is possible with a 2D raster).

Comment: Regrouping should be possible using r.reclass. Reclass rules can be specified in a .txt file if wanted. Do you have an example of data and to which value you want to group? r.reclass: https://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/r.reclass.html